# Python: writing hindi characters to csv

Tags: python, csv, encoding, character-encoding, hindi

I am trying to write hindi to a csv in Python, eg:

```
import csv
posts = open('test.csv', mode='w', errors='ignore')
post_writer_hindi = csv.writer(posts, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
post_writer_hindi.writerow(['नमस्ते'])
```

This results in nothing being actually written. How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open('test.csv', mode='w', errors='ignore')` set the encoding to `encoding = 'utf-8'` so it will be `open('test.csv', mode='w', encoding = 'utf-8', errors='ignore')`